# Date of birth validation issues

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having an issue with date of birth validation.  It seems to work fine in Chrome/Firefox etc but doesn't work in IE.  We'd like the format of the dob to be 01/01/2017 for example or 1/1/2017 but IE will accept 01/01/17 for some reason.

```
<form name="patientDetailsForm" action="/saveCustomer" method="post">
<input name="dob" class="optionalbox form-control-small" id="dob" 
required="required" type="text" maxlength="10" pattern="^(?:(?:31(\/)(?:0?
[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-
9]\d)?
\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579]
[26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/)(?:
(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$" value="01/12/1985" 
autocomplete="off" minlength="10" maxlength="10">
<button class="button" type="submit" value="Save">Save Customer</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I’d suggest you use a date input field to begin with, instead of this regex pattern nonsense. Using regex to validate dates is one of the dumbest ideas one could possibly come up with.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#Using_date_inputs

Comment: isnt type="date" not supported in IE?  I forgot to mention it must work in IE as this is what they use.

Comment: Also - looking at type="date" in ie there's no validation it will accept anything you type into the box.

Comment: actually - input type date, does not work in IE : https://caniuse.com/#search=date

Comment: But you can use a datepicker.